# I am on the day 19th of [doing X]

Tags: grammar, american-english

can I say that

I am on the day 19th of fasting from rudeness, backingbiting, cursing, food and drinking during the daylight.

I will include you in my prayer

Comment: Say "day 19" or "19th day." Ordinal numbers are used as adjectives in English.  "Fasting" can only be applied to food and drink.  "Abstaining" would be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry, we can't help answer generic "is this sentence ok"-style questions. But if you're worried about some specific aspect or detail of the sentence, please ask about it, and we'll be happy to address that.

Comment: Spelling - "backbiting" not  "backingbiting"

Comment: Do you intend to binge when the fast is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me rewrite as follows:

I am on my 19th day of fasting during daylight hours, abstaining from rudeness, backbiting, cursing, overeating and drinking.

(Thanks for your prayers!)

Comment: so he's "abstaining from rudeness," but he's still backbiting, cursing, overeating and drinking?  The comma after "hours" needs to be replaced by "and".

Comment: I believe otherwise. I'm on my 19th day.... (I am) abstaining from...

Comment: My pleasure. Happy Ramadan!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is the sentence you're asking to be proofread?

> I am on the day 19th of fasting from rudeness, backingbiting, cursing, food and drinking during the daylight.

Your sentence is not grammatically correct, the first part of it poses problems:

> I am on the day 19th of...

These constructions would be correct:

> - I am on *the 19th day* of...
> - I am on *day 19* of...

In the first example here, *19th* is a premodifier for *day* while in the second phrase, *day 19* can be seen as one unit.

The first construction uses an *ordinal number* which typically precedes the noun it modifies. However, in dates this is normally the other way around:

> November 3rd, December 25th,...

**BUT:**

> The third **of** November, the 25th **of** December

In this last example, the ordinal numbers precede the ellipted word *day* and *of November/of December* are postmodifiers.